# How to automate building and deploying a BPEL application

Tags: deployment, automation, weblogic, bpel, jdeveloper

I need to automate the building and deployment of (several) BPEL applications to a weblogic server.

I now do it using jDeveloper 11g, but I guess there should be some command line tools to do it. (I come from a Microsoft /.NET / Visual Studio background, and I can automate the deployment of my .NET applications using the command line and msbuild)

Does anyone know how to do that via the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any experience with BPEL on Oracle WebLogic but according to [this documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E10291_01/doc.1013/e10538/weblogic.htm) a BPEL application is packaged as a standard EAR. I don't know exactly how your sources are structured under JDeveloper but you best option here to automate the packaging and the deployment of this EAR is IMO to use [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) (or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) but if all this is totally new for you I would recommend using Ant).

Maybe [this tutorial](http://upog.wordpress.com/2009/10/18/ejb3-helloworld-example-using-weblogic-10-3/) can help you to get started for the packaging part (basically, how to use the [ear](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ear.html) task). And for the deployment, I suggest to use the [wldeploy](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/programming/wldeploy.html) Ant task (which wraps the `weblogic.Deployer` utility). I've mentioned them in [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131687/how-to-remote-deploy-an-application-in-weblogic).

Also have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514453/ant-job-to-invoke-jdeveloper-to-create-ear-file-with-specified-deploy-file), it seems that JDeveloper might have some support to achieve this task (but I have zero knowledge of it so I can't provide any guidance, JDeveloper is not really widely used).

Comment: I'm going to use Cruise Control, so I'd like to use command line tools (not ant tasks). I'll check out some of those links

Comment: @Juan Invoking an Ant script is perfectly suitable for cruisecontrol (that's the common use case) but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I asked the QC department, and they told me I have the ability to use Hudson, which I believe can use Ant Tasks, so perhaps I'll just do that then

Comment: Oh, I never did that from CC, perhaps you're right. I'll go with hudson though that's more likely to deal with Java than CC

Comment: Both CC and Hudson can deal with Java but if you have the choice, pick up Hudson, it's much easier to use. And let me insist, Ant (or Maven) are the common tools to automate a Java build and Ant/Maven can be invoked by any decent continuous integration engine.

Comment: @Pascal: I assume this is BPEL Process Manager. If so, the core application is deployed as an EAR, but the actual BPEL processes are not; in Oracle SOA Suite 10g, BPEL processes are packaged as BPEL Suitcases (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B31017_01/integrate.1013/b28981/deployproc.htm), and in Oracle SOA Suite 11g, they are packaged as SOA Composite applications (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15523_01/integration.1111/e10224/sca_lifecycle.htm).

Comment: @Pascal: You gave a good answer on how to deploy generic enterprise applications (EAR) on WebLogic. However, my guess is that this is not what the questioner needed; he needs to know how to automate deployment of BPEL processes, which does not involve EARs at all, and has a different set of deployment tools.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Oracle SOA Suite 11g? If so, have a look at [Oracle Fusion Middleware Developer's Guide for Oracle SOA Suite](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15523_01/integration.1111/e10224/toc.htm), particularly the section [38.7 Deploying SOA Composite Applications](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15523_01/integration.1111/e10224/sca_lifecycle.htm#CHDBAJIB) and the subsection *38.7.5 Managing SOA Composite Applications with Scripts*.

You may also find useful advice in the [Oracle BPEL forums](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=212).